# Datepicker keep reseting me the other input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have an input field text with a datapicker below:

```
 <input type="type" class="form-control" name="cost" v-bind:value="cost">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8">

       <label class="col-md-2 control-label" >From:</label>
        <datepicker  v-model="period.from" :format="period.format" id="vue-time-picker"
                    :clear-button="true"
                    name="from"></datepicker>

       <br>
       <label class="col-md-2 control-label" >To:</label>
        <datepicker v-model="period.to" :format="period.format" id="vue-time-picker"
                    :clear-button="true"
                    name="to"></datepicker>
    </div>
```

I am using vuejs-datepicker and all the time I fill the first field and as soon as I select a date it will reset me the input text to old value ?

Does anyone has a solution for this ?

Comment: My first guess is the id of the datepicker (twice)

Comment: @ThomasKleßen I removed the id's and its still reseting the values

Comment: I have similar issue with a date picker. It seems the data wasn't binding when the date is populated by the date picker, `v-on:input` does not fire. Using `:value` instead of `v-modal` solved it for me since I do not need 2-way binding.

Answer (score 0):

duplicated id value `id="vue-time-picker"`

`input type="type"` seems wrong too

Comment: fixed both still its reseting me the other field when I select a date

Comment: add a snipet of your code or show us your javascript. It might be that you are calling the class name which is the same and it reset the other value